# Hide part of shape with transparency?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to hide part of what you have drawn in SVG without drawing over it with another shape?

For example, I'm trying to create a empty circle with a slice cut out of one part. I was able to achieve the look I wanted but the image isn't transparent on the slice I want to hide. If I change the background color of the page it's on, I'd have to change the color of the rect as well.

I've looked into SVG clipping but it looks like that is for hiding what's outside of an area while I'm looking to do the inverse. Am I going about this the wrong way?

[image]

```html
<svg width="60" height="60">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" stroke-width="8" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;" />
  <rect height="8" width="22" y="26" fill="lightblue"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What about a boolean operation? Draw your circle, draw the rect, then subtract the rect from the circle.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction to learn how to do that?

Comment: Well, using Inkscape, I'd do the following. (0) Draw the 48px circle (1) draw a 32px circle. Select the larger one and then subtract the smaller one from it. This will give you a black path (that looks like a circle with a fairly thick stroke) (2) Draw the rect (3) Select the circle and subtract the rect from it.

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to write the code by hand actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I was looking for was a SVG `mask`.

I had to create a mask on the circle that consisted of two parts:

1. A white rect that covered the entire image **(white: show)**
2. A black rect of what I wanted to hide **(black: hide)**

Code shown below.

```html
<svg width="60" height="60">
  <defs>
    <mask id="slice">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <rect height="8" width="22" y="26" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" stroke-width="8" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;" mask="url(#slice)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Looks like a short, succinct solution. Even better, one you were able to derive yourself. (and I might add, much better than the one I had to offer) Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to use an [arc](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands)?

```html
<svg width="12cm" height="5.25cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  
  
 <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M 225,225 a150,150 0 1,1 0,100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="25"/>
</svg>
```